# VS2010 how to connect .h to its .cpp OUTSIDE of project's directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

This should be simple but I'm losing sleep over it :(

I have a couple of classes split into .h and .cpp that I placed together into a separate 'classes' folder outside of the project's so that multiple projects can access them.

Under project properties->VC++ Directory
I changed the 'include directories' parameter with the full path of my 'classes' folder.

The .h from my classes seem to be usable within the projects but my .cpp are not being linked to correctly as they are causing "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol" problems when I compile. I cannot find the solution in similar forum threads about linking problems...

```
//this is how the .cpp starts
//is the path wrong ? Am I missing a VS2010 setting somewhere ?
//I've tried several alternatives including full path name, brackets..
#include "CMyClass.h"
```

My directory looks like this under "..\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\"

```
project_one //wants to use a class from the 'classes' folder
project_two //also wants to use a class from the 'classes' folder
classes //.h and .cpp are in here
```

The classes have been tested in their own consoles so the definitions are definitely there. The classes are in a new directory separate from the project.

How to make them find their .cpp ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each project, right-click on it and select 'Add existing item...' and select your shared CPP files.  Each CPP file has to be added to each project where it is used.  This does not duplicate the CPP files on disk and it doesn't matter if they are located outside of the project directory on the disk.